# Particle reflections in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, particle-system

I am using Swift 2.2, SpriteKit, iOS-target is 9.0. Is it possible to let particles produced by the built-in particle-engine be reflected by other objects?

Comment: No (if by reflected you meant its position being updated due to collision resolution)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for your response!